# Global name helper is not defined in Python even though function is present

Tags: python, oop

I am working on this problem https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs and getting an error 'global name helper is not defined'. But it is defined in the class?

```
class Solution(object):
    def climbStairs(self, n, ):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """

        return helper(0, n)

    def helper(self, curr, n):
        if (curr > n):
            return 0

        if (curr == n):
            return 1

        return helper(curr + 1, n) + helper(curr + 2, n)
```

Comment: It's `self.helper(...)`. And additionally unlike in Java you don't have to bundle functions in classes.

Answer (score 0):

`helper` is a bound function of a `Solution` instance, you need to call it on `self`.

as per the timeout error on bigger inputs, that's because you make 2 recursive calls per call to `helper`, which means a runtime complexity of `O(2^N)`.

because many of the calls are with the same arguments, you can use [`functools.lrucache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to cache results of previous calls, which reduces it to `O(N)`

```py
from functools import lru_cache

class Solution(object):
    def climbStairs(self, n, ):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """

        return self.helper(0, n)

    @lru_cache()
    def helper(self, curr, n):
        if (curr > n):
            return 0

        if (curr == n):
            return 1

        return self.helper(curr + 1, n) + self.helper(curr + 2, n)


s = Solution()
print(s.climbStairs(35))
```

Comment: Still a run time error. When I added self to the first helper call in the climbStairs function, it's a timeout error when the input is 35.

Comment: @ivymatch I edited my answer with a solution to the timeout error as well

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the 'self' argument for helper i.e replacing helper() with self.helper() should hopefully work.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def climbStairs(self, n, ):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """

        return self.helper(0, n)

    def helper(self, curr, n):
        if (curr > n):
            return 0

        if (curr == n):
            return 1

        return self.helper(curr + 1, n) + self.helper(curr + 2, n)
```